# Docker postgres how to share database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm running a PostgreSQL db via docker postgres. 
I have populated the db with lots of data and would like to share it with others.

Is there a way to 'save' this database with all the data as a new image and publish it to a Docker registry so it can be easily pulled and used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker container commit` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/ to create an image from a container.

Then you can publish that image to a docker registry for use by others.

Comment: perfect answer @emory thanks. One question. I'm using volumes and according to documentation 'The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes mounted inside the container'. Any workaround for this? Cheers

Comment: In fact, i think 'docker container commit' is a kludge solution.  1. If the data is in a volume it wont work. 2. It forces the receiver to use a specific database.  Surely postgres has an export data feature.  mysql can produce a file of sql statements that will recreate a database.

Comment: Alternatively if the data is in a directory say /srv/data.  Then you can use 'docker container cp dbcontainer:/srv/data mydir ' to copy the data to a directory on your host system.  You can share this data dir with others who can mount it.

Comment: If the data is in a volume then you can run another shortlived container with the data volume mounted.  You can tarball it to a 2nd mounted dir - a folder on ur host system.  The advantage of this approach is u can do it,while the db container is stopped ... so you do not need to worry about data being on an inconsistent state.